# Error while installing Iron Meteor on Windows7/Windows8

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I am trying to install iron-router on Windows but i am unable to install.
Below are the steps i tried

Created packages folder in my project.
Cloned iron -router(version 0.8.2) repo.
Then ran meteor add iron-router
My smart.json file looks like this

```
{
  "name": "iron-router",
  "description": "Routing specifically designed for Meteor",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router",
  "author": "Chris Mather (https://github.com/cmather), Tom Coleman   (https://github.com/tmeasday)",
  "version": "0.8.2",
  "git": "https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router.git",
  "packages": {
  "iron-layout": "0.2.0"
  }
}
```

But i am getting the following error 
    iron-router: updating npm dependencies -- connect...=> Errors while scanning packages:

```
While building package `iron-router`:
error: no such package: 'iron-layout'
```

My Meteor Version is 0.8.3  What can i do to resolve this error ? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Meteor is not compatible with windows yet because windows does not support [symlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) .

There are some unofficial solutions [here](http://win.meteor.com/)

Your best bet is going for the VM solution as the ported version is heavily outdated.
And you would also need a ported version of meteorite. VM setup tutorial [here](https://gist.github.com/gabrielhpugliese/5855677)

My team also made a default meteor development vm setup [here](https://github.com/gfk-ba/meteor-dev-vm)

Comment: @sri85 Then you will also need windows compatible version of meteorite that doesn't exist. I would recommend you to try https://github.com/gfk-ba/meteor-dev-vm

Answer (score 0):

This is how I add packages to Windows Meteor Version is 0.8.3:

1. Download the zip from the github page of package.
   (in this case [iron-router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/archive/dev.zip))
2. Extract zip and rename it to original package name
   (in this case iron-router)
3. Put the folder inside "packages" folder of my application
4. Check for the dependencies (in this case: blaze-layout, deps-ext)
5. Download the dependencies, rename if necessary and put in packages folder.
6. Now: meteor add iron-router